# Separation of the dataframes by row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to split my dataframe based on the first row to generate four separate dataframes (for subgroup analysis). I have a 172x106 Excel file, where the first row consists of either a 1, 2, 3, or 4. The other 171 lines are radiomic features, which I want to copy to the ''new'' dataset. The columns do not have headernames. My data looks like the following:

```
{0: [4.0, 0.65555056, 0.370511262, 16.5876203, 44.76954415, 48.0, 32.984845, 49.47726751, 49.47726751, 13133.33333, 29.34869973, 0.725907513, 3708.396349, 0.282365204, 13696.0, 2.122884402, 3.039611259, 1419.058749, 1.605529827, 0.488297449], 1: [2.0, 0.82581372, 0.33201741, 20.65753167, 62.21821817, 50.59644256, 62.60990337, 55.56977596, 77.35631842, 23890.66667, 51.38065822, 0.521666786, 7689.706847, 0.321870752, 25152.0, 1.022813615, 1.360453239, 548.2156387, 0.314035581, 0.181204079]}
```

I wanted to use `groupby`, but since the column headers have no name, it makes it hard to implement. This is my current code:

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel(r'H:\Documenten\MATLAB\sample_file.xlsx',header=None)
Class_1=df.groupby(df.T.loc[:,0])
df_new = Class_1.get_group("1")
print(df_new)
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/PycharmProjects/RadiomicsPipeline/spearman_subgroups.py", line 5, in <module>
    df_new = Class_1.get_group("1")
  File "C:\Users\cpullen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 754, in get_group
    raise KeyError(name)
KeyError: '1'
```

How do I implement the separation of the dataframes by row values?

Comment: Could you [edit] to include a sample of your data as actual text instead of a screenshot please? (eg: the output of `df.head(20).to_dict('list')`)

Comment: Or having said that with possibly duplicated column names... maybe just `print(df.head(20))`...

Comment: @JonClements I have added the first two colums, I hope it is what you are meaning

Comment: May I ask that you are trying to group the column with the same first row value as one?

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew I want to group the columns based on the values in the first row. Thus, all columns with the first row value of 1 is one separate dataframe, all columns with the first row value of 2 is one dataframe etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that this is the result you want. If not, please clearly show the desired output.

You can simply achieve what you want by transposing your dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

n = 5
data = np.stack((np.random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4], n), np.random.rand(n), np.random.rand(n), np.random.rand(n)), axis=0)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df.head()`:

```
0   1   2   3   4
0   1.000000    4.000000    2.000000    1.000000    4.000000
1   0.857946    0.847252    0.623564    0.384382    0.297535
2   0.056713    0.272656    0.477665    0.812169    0.479977
3   0.392785    0.836079    0.337396    0.648172    0.368242
```

```
df_transpose = df.transpose()
df_transpose.columns = ['group'] + list(df_transpose.columns.values[1:])
```

`df_transpose.head()`:

```
group   1   2   3
0   1.0 0.857946    0.056713    0.392785
1   4.0 0.847252    0.272656    0.836079
2   2.0 0.623564    0.477665    0.337396
3   1.0 0.384382    0.812169    0.648172
4   4.0 0.297535    0.479977    0.368242
```

```
list_df = dict()

for group in set(df_transpose['group']):
    list_df[group] = df_transpose.loc[df_transpose['group'] == group]
```

`list_df`:

```
{
 1.0:
     group         1         2         3
     0    1.0  0.857946  0.056713  0.392785
     3    1.0  0.384382  0.812169  0.648172,
 2.0:
     group         1         2         3
     2    2.0  0.623564  0.477665  0.337396,
 4.0:
     group         1         2         3
     1    4.0  0.847252  0.272656  0.836079
     4    4.0  0.297535  0.479977  0.368242
}
```

Individual dataframes:

`list_df[1.0]`, `list_df[2.0]`, `list_df[3.0]` (which does not exist in this example), `list_df[4.0]`

(BTW. I defined a wrong variable name. The name should be `dict_df`, not `list_df`.)

Comment: This is indeed what I was looking for! Can I also save the different groups to individual dataframes, so that I have four different dataframes? I want to use that for further calculations.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, after importing the dataframe, sort the value of the first row in order

```
df
Out[26]: 
   0  1  2  3
0  0  1  0  1
1  1  2  5  8
2  2  3  6  9
3  3  4  7  0

df = df.sort_values(by = 0, axis = 1)

Out[30]:
   0  2  1  3
0  0  0  1  1
1  1  5  2  8
2  2  6  3  9
3  3  7  4  0
```

You should have a dataframe with ordered 1st row values. After that, you can use `df.iloc` to rename your column name and you will drop the first row.

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]

0  0  0  1  1
0  0  0  1  1
1  1  5  2  8
2  2  6  3  9
3  3  7  4  0

df.drop(0, inplace=True)

df.drop(0)
Out[51]: 
0  0  0  1  1
1  1  5  2  8
2  2  6  3  9
3  3  7  4  0
```

Eventually, you can do slicing based on the column name.

```
df_1 = df[1]

df_1
Out[56]: 
0  1  1
1  2  8
2  3  9
3  4  0
```